# How to use Log4Cplus in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, log4cplus

What is the best practice to use Log4Cplus in a DLL  ?

I want to use a FileAppender.

I have a win32 DLL, that has DLLMain, and 3 exported Function.

Where do I define the Appender and Layout object ? Where to set their properties ? 
Where do I link them to a logger ?

I want to use the logger in all classes inside the dll I guess by just calling:

```
Logger myLogger= Logger::getInstance("myLoggerName");
```

where should I put the code so I can have the log4cplus macros enabled and working in all my functions inside the dll ?

In a normal program I will use global variables, use main or some ctor to set them up and then everything can see them. 
What do I do inside a dll ?

(I don't want to call the setup code in every exported function, but only once when dll is loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where do I define the Appender and Layout object? Where to set their properties? Where do I link them to a logger?

Generally, I think that your DLL should have some `MyDLLInit()` function that you can call that would configure log4cplus according to your needs.

> Where should I put the code so I can have the log4cplus macros enabled and working in all my functions inside the DLL?

You should not need to do anything special here. Just include the `loggingmacros.h` to get the macros and use them.

> In a normal program I will use global variables, use main or some ctor to set them up and then everything can see them. What do I do inside a DLL?

It seems to me that using a global `Logger` instance (that would be initialized by your `MyDLLInit()` function) is OK. But if your DLL has some kind of "context" handle that it returns to its users, use that instead and stick the `Logger` instance into the "context" handle instead.

> (I don't want to call the setup code in every exported function, but only once when dll is loaded)

This should not be necessary.

See the tests sources that are part of the source distribution, use them as examples of how you can instantiate `Appender` and `Layout`. E.g., [`fileappender_test`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~log4cplus/log4cplus/1.1.x/view/head:/tests/fileappender_test/main.cxx)

### UPDATE

You do not have to keep either the Appender or the Layout in any of your own variables. Both are managed by log4cplus. After you do `logger.addAppender(myappender)` (corresponding to line 23 in the `fileappender_test` linked above), all of the variables including `myappender` can get out of scope and can be destroyed because the Appender is managed by the Logger and Appender's layout is managed by the Appender.

Comment: I have several CPP files, but holds the exports.  I've added 2 global params: SharedAppenderPtr, and std::auto_ptr<Layout> to this one. I initialize them in my own GetLogger function (with a flag to prevent it to be done more than once) than I use GetInstance and return the Logger object.  I hope it should work, I am not sure that global vars behaviour is dll is defined, but this works for me. I am not sure yet what to do with other classes in the dll, should I pass the logger in their CTOR ? (they are not accessed from outside the dll)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I understand that once I add the appender to the logger each time I use getlogger  I get a "good" logger ? I will try it.